# is xbox music available in india?

Tags: xbox-music

I have music + videos in my phone and I want to have xbox music in my windows 8 nokia lumia 620 phone. and when I tried to install it, it says this service is not available in your region.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, but you can vote for it here http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4042524-xbox-music-and-xbox-video-for-india